# Pass java variable/array to javascript in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, graph

Hi I want to use google graph to plot graph in android webview. I am calling a web service to get the data. I just need to pass those data to javascript to plot the graph. Here is the data that using by google graph api.

```
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Frequency', 'HVAC', 'Lighting', 'Overall', 'Cost'],
          ['00:00',100,200,0,80],
          ['00:00',0,0,522,50],
          ['1:00',125,78,0,115],
          ['1:00',0,0,153,125],
          ['2:00',100,90,0,100],
          ['2:00',0,0,119,120]
        ]);
```

and graph options like

```
var options = {
          title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
          vAxis: {title: "Cups"},
          hAxis: {title: "Month"},
          seriesType: "bars",
          isStacked: true,
          series: {3: {type: "line"}}

        };
```

I think this is a javascript array. I need to pass the data to javascript. Can I pass this kind of array from an android context to javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass strings via webview.loadUrl("javascript:myfunction(arg1, ..)") to the webview, but the string can also contain JSON data. Inside the javascript function i.e. myfunction you call JSON.parse(arg1) to convert the string back to a javascript object.